# Computer restarts while gaming

Tags: games

My machine consistently spontaneously restarts while gaming, (e.g., while playing Risk of Rain 2 through SteamPlay after as short at 3 minutes or as long as 15 minutes).

System details

- Ubuntu 19.10 Memory: 15.6 GiB
- Processor: Intel Core i5-7600K CPU @3.80GHZ x 4
- Graphics: AMD Navi10
- GNOME: 3.34.2 OS type 64-bit

Steps I have tried

- turned off all overclocking
- ran Memtest86+ for over an hour; no errors
- swapped power supply; same result
- checked for latest graphics drivers; says it's up to date
- checked temperatures at time of crash; CPU at 37C, GPU at 70C

Comment: Ubuntu does not have a "spontaneous restart" feature, so look at hardware faults. The two most common hardware faults are thermal and power supply. But neither is related to Ubuntu....

Comment: This is more likely from accessing memory. That game probably addresses memory it should not and that leads to a crash with restart. If you want to track this down you need to start tracing that program. But I do agree: this is not an Ubuntu issue. Risk of Rain 2 itself is likely the cause.

Comment: Check the logs with `sudo journalctl -b -1 -e`. That command will show you the end of the previous boot's logs.

Comment: It's all full of "Window manager warning: last_user_time (19484979) is greater than comparison timestamp (19484977).  This most likely represents a buggy client sending ina
Window manager warning: 0x5400001 appears to be one of the offending windows with a timestamp of 19484979.  Working around..."